# Which one is preferable here- "later" or "after"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs

The situation is that we are meeting at 2 pm and an officer gives an instruction regarding coming on time. In this context, which one of the following is correct?

> If you come at 2:10 pm or ***later***, I will not let you in.
>
> If you come at 2:10 pm or ***after***, I will not let you in.

If neither is correct, what is a correct way of saying this?

I want to know the difference between 'later' and 'after', so expressions based on "10 min late" etc. are not needed at this time.

Comment: Some more ways (but it uses neither *later* nor *after*) to say this: *If you don't come before 2:10 p.m., I won't let you in. I won't let you in after 2:10 p.m.* (I hope you or your meeting participants wouldn't want to be too precise and argue what if someone came during the window of 2:09.30 p.m to 2:10.59 p.m. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct; however, I would opt for "later". "Later" is more commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

However, I don't think `at 2:10pm` is really needed.

You could rather say:

> If you come later than 2:10pm, I won't let you in.